Elasticsearch: Unexpected Behavior with ICU Collation Keyword Sorting
I am experiencing unexpected behavior with the sorting order of documents in Elasticsearch using the icu_collation_keyword field type. Here are the details:
Steps to Reproduce:
PUT /test-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id422": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "collated": {
            "type": "icu_collation_keyword",
            "strength": "tertiary",
            "case_level": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Index the Documents:
POST /test-index/_doc/1
{ "id422": "0a11" }

POST /test-index/_doc/2
{ "id422": "0A11" }

POST /test-index/_doc/3
{ "id422": "0b11" }

POST /test-index/_doc/4
{ "id422": "0B11" }

POST /test-index/_doc/5
{ "id422": "0c11" }

POST /test-index/_doc/6
{ "id422": "0C11" }

Search and Sort:

GET /test-index/_search
{
  "sort": [
    { "id422.collated": { "order": "asc" } }
  ],
  "_source": ["id422"]
}

Expected Sort Order:
0A11
0B11
0C11
0a11
0b11
0c11
Actual Sort Order:
The response includes unexpected characters in the sort field, and the order does not match the expected case-sensitive sorting.
Response:
0a11
0A11
0b11
0B11
0c11
0C11
The sort fields of the response contain unexpected cryptic characters like:
"sort": [
"""কՅ‡ࡀ



Additional Information:

Elasticsearch version: 8.15.3

Kibana version: 8.15.3

ICU Analysis plugin version: 8.15.3


Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

What do you understand "strength": "tertiary" to mean?

strength: "tertiary":
Defines the level of differentiation for collation comparisons:
primary: Ignores accents and case differences.
secondary: Considers accents but ignores case differences.
tertiary: Considers case and accent differences.
In this case, "tertiary" is used, which means that sorting will consider both case and accents.
case_level: true:
This flag indicates that the collation should be case-sensitive.
When case_level is set to true, uppercase and lowercase letters are treated differently even if the strength level is set to a lower setting like primary or secondary.

See also https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu-collation-keyword-field.html
